# Git last version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, command-line-interface, ruby-on-rails-4

I was playing with my local app, trying to add devise and railsadmin which was disastrous and frustrating. I decided that it's best I just nuke everything that changed and go back to my last working git commit. But somehow my local version is different than my heroku production ver.

How do I get or pull down my heroku version to my local - or get that commit? I am trying to figure it out with docs and CLI commands but things just aren't clicking. I don't exactly understand how the versions could be different. (I made CSS changes during my last commit and it seems my local is a version behind?)

Thank you.

Comment: git pull heroku master
States that it's already up to date. But the versions are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you determining "the versions are different"?

As far as I know, if "git pull heroku master" says "already up-to-date", then the last commit on your current branch and the Heroku master branch are the same.

It is possible though that you have local changes which have not been committed to your local repo. In that case, `git reset --hard HEAD` will throw away your local changes and go back to your last commit. This should be the exact same commit as on Heroku. 
(NOTE: *only* do this if you *really* want to throw away local uncommitted changes!)